# Calculate number of days between two dates in php

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the number of days between 2 dates

Date format is dd/mm/yy

Dates are variable:

```
$getarrival   = $_GET["arrival"];
$getdeparture = $_GET["departure"];
```

I tried this but it is not working when you change the date format.

```
$start = strtotime('2010-01-25');
$end   = strtotime('2010-02-20');

$days_between = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
```

Comment: You say dd/mm/yy and then you use yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: consider using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class that comes with PHP. It eases the work with dates a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As my date format is dd/mm/yyyy I had change format of the date to yyyy/mm/dd and pass it to a new variable

```
list($arrivalday, $arrivalmonth, $arrivalyear) =explode("/",$getarrival);
list($departureday, $departuremonth, $departureyear) =explode("/",$getdeparture);
$newarrival = ($arrivalyear.'/'.$arrivalmonth.'/'.$arrivalday);
$newdeparture = ($departureyear.'/'.$departuremonth.'/'.$departureday);
$start = strtotime($newarrival);
$end = strtotime($newdeparture);
$totaldays = ceil(abs($end - $start) / 86400);
```